# Are there any more efficient ways for atomically adding two floats?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, c++03

I have a bundle of floats which get updated by various threads. Size of the array is much larger than the number of threads. Therefore simultaneous access on particular floats is rather rare. I need a solution for C++03.

The following code atomically adds a value to one of the floats ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pk6kq4cYIRuLVrbV)). Assuming it works it might be the best solution.
The only alternative I can think of is dividing the array into bunches and protecting each bunch by a mutex. But I don't expect the latter to be more efficient.

My  questions are as follows. Are there any alternative solutions for adding floats atomically? Can anyone anticipate which is the most efficient? Yes, I am willing to do some benchmarks. Maybe the solution below can be improved by relaxing the memorder constraints, i.e. exchanging `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` by something else. I have no experience with that.

```
void atomic_add_float( float *x, float add )
{
  int *ip_x= reinterpret_cast<int*>( x ); //1
  int expected= __atomic_load_n( ip_x, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST ); //2
  int desired;
  do  {
    float sum= *reinterpret_cast<float*>( &expected ) + add; //3
    desired=   *reinterpret_cast<int*>( &sum );
  } while( ! __atomic_compare_exchange_n( ip_x, &expected, desired, //4
                                          /* weak = */ true, 
                                          __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST ) );
}
```

This works as follows. At `//1` the bit-pattern of `x` is interpreted as an `int`, i.e. I assume that `float` and `int` have the same size (32 bits). At `//2` the value to be increased is loaded atomically. At `//3` the bit-pattern of the `int` is interpreted as `float` and the summand is added. (Remember that `expected` contains a value found at `ip_x == x`.) This doesn't change the value under `ip_x == x`. At `//4` the result of the summation is stored only at `ip_x == x` if no other thread changed the value, i.e. if `expected == *ip_x` ([docu](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins)). If this is not the case the do-loop continues and `expected` contains the updated value found ad `ip_x == x`.

GCC's functions for atomic access (`__atomic_load_n` and `__atomic_compare_exchange_n`) can easily be exchanged by other compiler's implementations.

Comment: @user463035818 For changing this into C code just exchange `reinterpret_cast` by classical C casts.

Comment: @ClaasBontus this might work for this question, unfortunately c++ answers dont always transform that easily to c answers (or vice versa). Please dont tag unrelated tags

Comment: Assuming that the code works correctly, this looks like a worthy candidate for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: In C++20 you will likely get `std::atomic<float>`, but not available right now. [P0020R6 Floating Point Atomic](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0020r6.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any alternative solutions for adding floats atomically? Can anyone anticipate which is the most efficient?

Sure, there are at least few that come to mind:

1. Use synchronization primitives, i.e. spinlocks. Will be a bit slower than compare-exchange.
2. Transactional extension ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions)). Will be faster, but this solution might limit the portability.

Overall, your solution is quire reasonable: it is fast and yet will work on any platform.

In my opinion the needed memory orders are:

- `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE` -- when we read the value in `__atomic_load_n()`
- `__ATOMIC_RELEASE` -- when `__atomic_compare_exchange_n()` is success
- `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE` -- when `__atomic_compare_exchange_n()` is failed

Comment: I don't think you are right. `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` updates `expected` if `expected != desired`. It is therefore sufficient to load `expected` only once outside the loop.

Comment: @ClaasBontus you are right, I confused the `__atomic_compare_exchange_n()` it with the Intel's CMPXCHG instruction... This means that we definitely need an `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE` ordering what it fails...

Answer (score 1):

To make this function more efficient you may like to use `__ATOMIC_ACQUIRE` for `__atomic_load_n` and `__ATOMIC_RELEASE` and `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` for `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` `success_memorder` and `failure_memorder` respectively.

On x86-64 though that does not change the generated assembly because its memory model is relatively strong. Unlike for ARM with its weaker memory model.

Comment: Sure, it does not matter for x86, but still `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` would be not enough for successful compare-exchange IMO...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy That `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` is only for reloading on `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` failure, successful `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` must do `__ATOMIC_RELEASE`. Read the documentation for the function, there are interesting details.

Comment: Sure, just misread the sentence `and __ATOMIC_RELAXED for __atomic_compare_exchange_n success_memorder`...